# How fast does the diamond lose the atoms at sunlight?

Tags: carbon-allotropes

recently I've read that the diamonds lose their atoms at sunlight on the surface. Would you be able to explain me how fast is the rate of this process? Does the diamond lose the atoms each time when is exposured at sunlgiht? Thank you. :)

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76709/will-a-solid-object-lose-or-gain-atoms-on-standing-over-time-without-being-acte

Answer (score 5):

Thats true, but even an UV lamp would take 10 bilion years to remove a microgram (one-million part of a gram). It is caused by carbon atoms oxidizing, forming CO2. This process is accelerated by the presence of UV light.

Comment: Does that mean that Graphene will disappear in UV light too? :)